# .jsp dynamic table creation

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to create a dynamic table within `.jsp`. I have been attempting to do so through scriptlets in the following way (***this is pseudocode***):

```
<%
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

writer.println("<table>");

while(records in request object){
    writer.println("<tr>" + request.getAttribute().toString() + "</tr>");
    }

writer.println("</table");
writer.close();
%>
```

While the above method can and does work, it is both discouraged, and *probably not* the best way of accomplishing this task.

To my point and question - *is there a better way to create such dynamic content?*

Comment: yes there is. Just create regular html tables. And inside it, write your logic. If you need dynamic elements in table, just create regular html table and inside it run a loop using foreach (JSTL tag or Spring tag) and dynamically create tds and trs, etc.

Comment: Could you provide the answer below, and include a pseudocode example? It would provide visual clarity.

Comment: @Mathew Before I could dig into my old code and find an example, somebody already answered. Anyway, check my answer it might help you in the future.

Comment: Thanks Faraz, I appreciate both the help and the support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done without scriptlets:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:if test="${not empty request.records}">

  <table>
    <c:forEach items="${request.records}" var="record">
       <tr><td> ${record} </td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </table>

</c:if>
```

Comment: something's missing: <%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

Answer (score 1):

You would need to include JSTL dependency on class path, and also configure it in Spring.

If you already have it configured in Spring, then you would create tds dynamically this way:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item1</th>
        <th>Item2</th>
        <th>Item3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <c: forEach items="${menus}" var="menu" varStatus="status">
                            <tr>
        <td>${menu.item1}</td>
        <td>${menu.item2}</td>
        <td>${menu.item3}</td>
    </tr>
    </c: forEach>
</tbody>                        
</table >
```

This `${menus}` is a list coming from backend It is a list of POJO that contains 3 fields item1, item2, and item3.
You would also need to include c name space in your .jsp file: `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

There are tons of examples of this on the internet. Just look Spring MVC and JSTL and Table. YOu will find many results.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Faraz Durrani. Regarding JSTL - is this the only acceptable way of doing it? I'm just curious to see what my options are, or if this is the full-stop industry standard.

Comment: JSTL is provided by Java EE. Spring is based on Java EE. I am not 100% certain but JSTL is the only thing I have seen when it comes to looping thru items in a JSP. I think `spring tags` could also be used for looping, but I am not sure. But every book that I have read, and every tutorial I have seen, they all use JSTL.

Comment: JSTL is a industry standard. Yes. This I am 100 % confident of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "out" to print to the response. Why are you doing the first line? Where did you get that?

You could just do the following:

```html
<%
out.println("<table>");

while (records in request object){
    out.println("<tr>" + request.getAttribute().toString() + "</tr>");
}

out.println("</table>");
%>
```

Comment: This fails to really answer the question.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to point out, that you could at first make the code easier. not needed: "PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();"
wrong, because closing tag not closed: "writer.println("</table");"
don't try to close the reponse before the jsp ends: "writer.close();"